# Mac Software that launches and keeps applications running (for kiosk)

Tags: osx

I have used this Windows software for PC based kiosks
http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/

It allows the scheduling and custom startup of various applications as well as monitoring applications and services in case they crash.

Is there something similar for the Mac?